# Wordpress - Rewrite old URLs

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

We've changed our permalink-structure from `/archive/%post_id%` to `/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/` for better SEO.

Now we have the problem, that all old URLs on Facebook for example are pointing to a 404 page.

Is it possible to rewrite the old URLs to the new format?

Answer (score 0):

Added the following code to my themes functions.php

```
// Adding a new rule
/**
 * Adds a new rewrite rule.
 *
 * @param array $rules Existing rewrite rules.
 * @return array (Maybe) modified list of rewrites.
*/
function wpdocs_insert_rewrite_rules( $rules ) {
    $newrules = array();
    $newrules['archive/(\d*)$'] = 'index.php?postname=$matches[1]&post_id=$matches[2]';
    return $newrules + $rules;
}
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array','wpdocs_insert_rewrite_rules' );

// Adding the id var so that WP recognizes it
function wpdocs_insert_query_vars( $vars ) {
    array_push( $vars, 'id' );
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars','wpdocs_insert_query_vars' );
```

Answer (score -1):

Will be better to make redirection 301 from old to news.
Several rules in the .htaccess should work.

Comment: I didn't try to achieve to forward my URLs by 301! I want to rewrite them with wordpress, like my answer assumes.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use plugin "Simple 301 Redirects" to redirects from your old URLs to your new URLs.
You can dowload it at here https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/

Comment: I didn't try to achieve to forward my URLs by 301! I want to rewrite them with wordpress, like my answer assumes.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to 301 old URLs to the new, a WordPress plugin called 'Eggplant 301 Redirects' works really well.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/eps-301-redirects/

Comment: I didn't try to achieve to forward my URLs by 301! I want to rewrite them with wordpress, like my answer assumes.